# Get minimum values from array of objects using Distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of Object thats shows following data:

```
Arrival City|| Arrival Country      || Journey Date || Non-Stop Price || One-Stop Price || Multi-Stop Price
===========================================================================================================
SYD ||  AU ||   4/9/2014  ||    -   ||  -           ||863.79          ||903.29          || 
DEL ||  IN ||   4/10/2014 ||    -   ||  -           ||820.00          ||750.70          ||
SYD ||  AU ||   4/10/2014 ||    -   ||  -           ||923.70          ||903.70          ||
SYD ||  AU ||   4/15/2014 ||    -   ||  -           || 1455.91        ||1021.40         ||
CHI ||  US ||   4/25/2014 ||    -   ||  -           || -              ||191.90          ||146.00
CHI ||  US ||   5/1/2014  ||    -   ||  -           || -              ||201.90          ||143.00
```

The above table displays the City pair with their fares. 
    I want the lowest prices for each date, i.e For date 4/10/2014 the lowest of all three types of prices - should be - 750.70

I tried Linq to get distict dates but I dont know how to get lowest fare for that specific date.

```
    var distict = result.Select(p => p.JourneyDate).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be easiest by first doing a GroupBy on date, and then getting the Min value of your Non-Stop Price for your dates.

```
x.GroupBy(s => s.Date
            ).Select(s => new { 
                Date = s.Key, 
                Price = s.SelectMany(f => new Decimal[] { f.NonStopPrice, f.MultiStopPrice, f.OneStopPrice }).Min() 
            });
```

I'm making the assumption that your prices are Decimals.

Comment: Thank You. But I want minimum of all Prices (OneStop,NonStop,Multistop) for each date. So Here for 4/10/2014 minumum price will be 750.70 from all 4 values.

Comment: Edited example for multiple price properties.

Comment: @PoojaKhatri can you valid the answer of Menno van den Heuvel ? thanks